# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class from which I want to get values from combo box and textboxes, but when I pass the value it shows the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

Here is the code

```
public class Device1
{
        public int dwMachineNumber = cboMachineNo.SelectedIndex;
        public int dwBaudrate = 9600;
        public int dwCommPort = CboComPort.SelectedIndex;
        public string dwIPAddress = tbIPAdd.Text.Trim();
        public int dwPort = int.Parse(tbPort.Text.Trim());
        public int dwPassWord = int.Parse(tbPwd.Text.Trim());
}

private bool OpenDevice(int flag)
{
    bool result = false;   
    int DEVICE_BUSY = 0;
    Device1 dww = new Device1();
    try{
       result = OpenCommPort(dww.dwMachineNumber,
                       dww.dwBaudrate, 
                       dww.dwCommPort, 
                       dww.dwIPAddress, 
                       dww.dwPassWord,
                       dww.dwPort,
                       flag);

}
```

Comment: Where is tb* defined?   And you are missing some code.... please post a more coherent block of code if you want help.

Comment: it is getting directly value but when i'm passing it through class it showing following error

Comment: Do you know which line the error is happening on?

Comment: You can't pass and object "through"/assign to a class.  Please give us some more code to help you.  Does all of this lye in a class called form?

Comment: @IndigoDelta my guess is the `CboComPort.SelectedIndex` line.

Comment: If you can even just tell us which line the error occurs on, we can porbably point you in the right direction.

Comment: NIx is right error is on 'cboComPort.selectedIndex' line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,  I think this is what you're trying to do..

You maybe want to create your Device1 class to look like this:

```
public class Device1
{
    public int dwMachineNumber;
    public int dwBaudrate;
    public int dwCommPort;
    public string dwIPAddress;
    public int dwPort;
    public int dwPassWord;

    public Device1(int dwMachineNumber, int dwBaudrate, int dwCommPort, string dwIPAddress, int dwPort, int dwPassWord)
    {
        this.dwMachineNumber = dwMachineNumber;
        this.dwBaudrate = dwBaudrate;
        this.dwCommPort = dwCommPort;
        this.dwIPAddress = dwIPAddress;
        this.dwPort = dwPort;
        this.dwPassWord = dwPassWord;
    }
}
```

Then in the code-behind of your Winforms form you need to add something similar to this:

```
    private void btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device1 myDevice1 = new Device1(cboMachineNo.SelectedIndex, 9600, cboComPort.SelectedIndex, tbIPAdd.Text.Trim(), int.Parse(tbPort.Text.Trim(), int.Parse(tbPwd.Text.Trim());

        // Now do something with your populated Device1 object.
    }
```

For this example, I added the code to the event handler of a button.  You need to add it where you want it to happen.

This code will take the values from the winform and pass them to the class.  I believe this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer completely because you're code sample is incomplete.  But an explanation of this error may help.

Basically you're trying to call a method or property on another class statically, but that method or property isn't marked as static.

Take a look at this sample,  it will not compile and throw the error you're getting:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

To fix this, we need to make the method DoSomething static like so:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This will now compile,  another option if you do not want the method to be static is to create an instance before you call it:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
        myClass1.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If your error is happening on the line:

```
public int dwCommPort = CboComPort.SelectedIndex;
```

I suspect you've got the name of the combo box wrong, or intellisense has selected the wrong item without you noticing.  I notice you start the names of your combo boxes with "cbo" however this one has upper case so I suspect the name here is wrong.

Comment: That line is not wrong if he has a method declared inside the same class he's calling it from.

Comment: @drharris  Yes you're right,  I realised that after posting and completely revised my answer.  Infact if it had even of been declared in another class it would have thrown a different error all together.

Comment: can you do me a favor can u gve me the code on which i get the value of winform to class and then call these value of class in method

Comment: how can i get the value from this line ` class CboComPort {
        public static int SelectedIndex
` i just wanted to get value from cboComPort but here ur defining it a class

Comment: I've just realised....   in the line:  public int dwCommPort = CboComPort.SelectedIndex;   you're trying to get the selected index of a combo box right?  I think you're naming is confusing the name of the combo box with a class name.  Try renaming that combo box to something different in the form designer then change it to match in the code (make sure you get the casing right, I notice it is different to the other combo boxes.)

Comment: I think when you typed that line, intellisense picked the name of a class and not the name of the combo box and you didnt realise.  The fact that it starts "Cbo" and not "cbo" is the clue

Comment: but how to get this value from the class i dont have that much idea

Comment: You've made it work for the line above that says "public int dwMachineNumber = cboMachineNo.SelectedIndex;"  You just need to do the same with the line that doesn't work and get the combo box's name right.  If you still cant figure it out then can you post complete code samples and I'll correct it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to start here, but the first step is that you probably want to create a constructor for your class.  Something like:

```
    public class Device1
    {
        public int dwMachineNumber;
        public int dwBaudrate;
        public int dwCommPort;
        public string dwIPAddress;
        public int dwPort;
        public int dwPassWord;

        public Device1(int machineNumber, int baudRate, int commPort, 
            string IPAddress, int port, int password)
        {
            dwMachineNumber = machineNumber;
            dwBaudrate = baudRate;
            dwCommPort = commPort;
            dwIPAddress = IPAddress;
            dwPort = port;
            dwPassWord = password;
        }
    }
```

Now, in your winform/webpage, whatever action triggers the OpenDevice method to be called would be responsible for building the `Device1` object, and you could then pass that into the OpenDevice method.

From the code behind your winform, you'd need to add the object creation.  I assume it's coming from a button press...

```
protected void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Device1 dww=new Device1(cboMachineNo.SelectedIndex,
        9600,
        CboComPort.SelectedIndex,
        tbIPAdd.Text.Trim(),
        int.Parse(tbPort.Text.Trim()),
        int.Parse(tbPwd.Text.Trim())
    );
    OpenDevice(flagValue,dww);
}

private bool OpenDevice(int flag, Device1 dww)
{
    bool result = false;

    int DEVICE_BUSY = 0;
    try
    {
        result = OpenCommPort(dww.dwMachineNumber,
            dww.dwBaudrate, dww.dwCommPort, dww.dwIPAddress, dww.dwPassWord,
            dww.dwPort, flag);

    }
}
```

Note that you're using `SelectedIndex` from the combo box, when you probably want `Int32.Parse(cboMachineNo.SelectedValue)` and the same for the other combo box.

Comment: i did that also but when i pass through constructor it show me the same error

Comment: i just simple wants to bring data from winfoam(combo box, text box) into class

Comment: How and from where do you currently call `OpenDevice()`  Add that code to your question and we'll dig a little deeper.

Comment: im calling OpenDevice from dll

Comment: and it is working without class but when i want to use class it having above error

Comment: That's not very helpful. You may have to describe your entire architecture before we can be of more use. At some point, the user interacts with the program to start this chain of events. Start there, and explain how the event bubbles through the program until it reaches the `OpenDevice()` call. Add that info to your question by editing it.  The encapsulation of Object Oriented Programming seems like it gets in the way when you start out, but you'll realize the value of it later on :-)

Comment: Kendrick i didnt Get :( what you wanna share

Comment: I know, that's just a minor error.  The major one lies in your architecture.  You need to go back and give us more information in the question before we can provide a full answer.

Comment: i just want to call an class on that class it has my winform(text box, combo box ) values just a simple case

Comment: In order to do that, you need an instance of the class, and you need to get the values into that instance.  You'd normally do this on the winform itself under a button click event, but I have no idea what's happening outside of the code you posted above.  If it worked without the class, you might want to consider just doing it that way, because I don't think your above class is adding much value right now anyway.  Again, I'm not sure because we don't have enough code to work with in your question.

Comment: you just leave above code, just try to guide me in making the program of o call an class on that class it has my winform(text box, combo box ) values just a simple case

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works.  You ask a good question, you get a good answer.  If you need a tutorial or more guidance than can be found in that format, you probably need to go out and do some reading on object oriented design, and programming in general.  There may also be forums out there which are more suited to that style of interactive question and answer format.